# Confusing htaccess file - Just need to add a 301 but it won't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to add a 301 redirect from 1 URL to another. However, i've taken on a htaccess which is very confusing (not my work), and when I go to add the 301 redirect rule at the bottom, it does not work and the htaccess breaks the site. Here is the htaccess file (i've masked the address with 'dummyadd'):

```
Options -Indexes


    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all



    RewriteEngine On

    # RewriteBase /dummyadd/public_html/

    RewriteRule ^category/30/tub-chairs-and-sofas$ http://www.dummyadd.co.uk/category/3/tub-chairs-and-sofas [R=301,L]


    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule category/(\d+)/.+ shop.php?sec=cat&cat=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule product/(\d+)/.+ shop.php?sec=prod&prod=$1 [L,QSA]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^VP\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/shop\.php" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^default\.aspx$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^Cat\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/shop\.php" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^cat\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/shop\.php" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^outdoor\.html\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/category\/7\/outdoor\-furniture/" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^chairs\.html\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/category\/1\/chairs\-and\-banquette\-seating/" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^office\.html\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/category\/22\/office\-furniture/" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^bar_stools\.html\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/category\/5\/stools\-and\-bar\-stools/" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^category\/30\/tub\-chairs\-and\-sofas$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/category\/3\/tub\-chairs\-and\-sofas" [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/$1" [R=301,L]

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]


    # Force compression for mangled `Accept-Encoding` request headers
    # https://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/pushing-beyond-gzipping-25601.html



            SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
            RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding



    # - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

    # Compress all output labeled with one of the following media types.
    #
    # (!) For Apache versions below version 2.3.7 you don't need to
    # enable `mod_filter` and can remove the ``
    # and `` lines as `AddOutputFilterByType` is still in
    # the core directives.
    #
    # https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype


        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE "application/atom+xml" \
                                      "application/javascript" \
                                      "application/json" \
                                      "application/ld+json" \
                                      "application/manifest+json" \
                                      "application/rdf+xml" \
                                      "application/rss+xml" \
                                      "application/schema+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.geo+json" \
                                      "application/vnd.ms-fontobject" \
                                      "application/x-font-ttf" \
                                      "application/x-javascript" \
                                      "application/x-web-app-manifest+json" \
                                      "application/xhtml+xml" \
                                      "application/xml" \
                                      "font/eot" \
                                      "font/opentype" \
                                      "image/bmp" \
                                      "image/svg+xml" \
                                      "image/vnd.microsoft.icon" \
                                      "image/x-icon" \
                                      "text/cache-manifest" \
                                      "text/css" \
                                      "text/html" \
                                      "text/javascript" \
                                      "text/plain" \
                                      "text/vcard" \
                                      "text/vnd.rim.location.xloc" \
                                      "text/vtt" \
                                      "text/x-component" \
                                      "text/x-cross-domain-policy" \
                                      "text/xml"




# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Expires headers                                                    |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Serve resources with far-future expires headers.
#
# (!) If you don't control versioning with filename-based
# cache busting, you should consider lowering the cache times
# to something like one week.
#
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html



    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

  # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Media files
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

  # Web fonts

    # Embedded OpenType (EOT)
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"

    # OpenType
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"

    # TrueType
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

  # Other
    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

Redirect 301 /category/31/bespoke-banquette-seating /category/29/banquette-seating
```

I've added the redirect at the bottom, which is not working and breaking the site

Any help, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are using `mod_rewrite` to match any URI start with `cat` in this  `RewriteRule ^cat\/?`  so category will be matched there and also in every `RewriteRule ^(.*)$` because this match everything so the last rule will not match unless excluded the URI in it from all `mod_rewrite` rules before.

Save your original .htaccess file and remove the last rule then between this line `Deny from all` and this `# Force compression for mangled`Accept-Encoding`request headers` put the following rules :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^category/30/tub-chairs-and-sofas$    category/3/tub-chairs-and-sofas [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category/31/bespoke-banquette-seating$    category/29/banquette-seating [R=301,L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule category/(\d+)/.+ shop.php?sec=cat&cat=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule product/(\d+)/.+   shop.php?sec=prod&prod=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteRule ^(VP|Cat|cat)/?(.*)$  shop\.php [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^default\.aspx$ / [R=301,L]


RewriteRule ^outdoor\.html/?$ category/7/outdoor-furniture [R=301,L,QSA]  
RewriteRule ^chairs\.html/?$  category/1/chairs-and-banquette-seating [R=301,L,QSA]    
RewriteRule ^office\.html/?    category/22/office-furniture [R=301,L,QSA]    
RewriteRule ^bar_stools\.html/?$    category/5/stools-and-bar-stools [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Clear browser cache the test.

Comment: Thanks Mohammed. It doesn't seem to work. I swapped out RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^cat\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/shop\.php" [R=301,L] with RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dummyadd\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(category/31/bespoke-banquette-seating|category/29/banquette-seating)
RewriteRule ^cat\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.dummyadd\.co\.uk\/shop\.php" [R=301,L]

Comment: @SunnyM still you have several match like this   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ , i will give safe solution , just wait

Comment: @SunnyM you have only one domain right ? dummyadd.co.uk only right?

Comment: I've done what you said but now i'm getting this error: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: @SunnyM add RewriteBase / after RewriteEngine On , clear cache then test

Comment: Thanks again, but still no joy. I'm receiving a 500 server using the amendment. Any other thoughts?

Comment: @SunnyM the original file was working right ? but when you add the last line error happened right?

Comment: yes that's correct. Oriignal worked fine, but when i added the 301 at the end, the site did not load and error'd

Comment: @SunnyM add this after RewriteEngine On     RewriteRule ^category/31/bespoke-banquette-seating  http://www.dummyadd.co.uk/category/29/banquette-seating [R=301,L] and remove the last rule with redirect , clear browser cache then test it

Comment: Fantastic - this worked! Thanks for your help, really appreciate this Mohammed

Comment: @SunnyM glad to help , Thanks

Comment: i'm having trouble with something else. Wondering if you could help me. I'm trying to make /blog.php?story=84&title=seating-ideas-for-restaurants a friendly URL, so i added this in the htaccess: RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ blog.php?story=84&title=$2 [NC] but no luck. Any ideas?